# issue in Response.Write issue in .aspx page

Tags: asp.net

this is  my Flash  file

```
 <param name="movie" value="Flash/HomeMaster.swf?SID=<%Response.Write(strSess);%>" />
```

in .cs  file
in i have  declare an varaiable called= **strSess**

in page load i have assisgned an value

```
strSess ="1234";
```

but when i run this  page i get an error  telling

**the name  strSess would not be  found**

what is the issue. an any one tell me
thank you

Comment: Put your code in a code block - then we'll be able to see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cs file:

```
public string strSess = "1234"
```

In your presentation:

```
<param name="movie" value="Flash/HomeMaster.swf?SID=<%=strSess%>" />
```

Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable needs to be public in order to be seen by the `.aspx` page.